# How is "acknowledge" used?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

I am trying to integrate my application with JMS Queues (using ActiveMQ). 
My requirement is, that once the message has been read from the input queue, message should not be removed from the queue. Rather I want to send an acknowledgement that application has received that message.

I am not able to understand the exact usage of property "acknowledge".

My code is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:int-jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<!-- Component scan to find all Spring components -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.poc.springinteg._7" />

<!--  -->
<bean id="remoteJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate" lazy-init="false"> 
    <property name="environment"> 
        <props> 
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://localhost:61616</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.apache.activemq.jndi</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="connectionFactoryNames">DefaultActiveMQConnectionFactory,QueueConnectionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="queue.SendReceiveQueue">org.apache.geronimo.configs/activemq-ra/JCAAdminObject/SendReceiveQueue</prop>
            <prop key="queue.SendQueue">org.apache.geronimo.configs/activemq-ra/JCAAdminObject/MDBTransferBeanOutQueue</prop> 
        </props> 
    </property> 
</bean> 

<bean id="remoteConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" lazy-init="false">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="remoteJndiTemplate"/>
    <property name="jndiName" value="QueueConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true" />
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

   <!-- writing queue  -->
    <bean id="destinationqueue"        
class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
       <constructor-arg index="0">
       <value>OutputQueue_7</value>
       </constructor-arg> 
   </bean>

<int:channel id="outbound"/>

<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="jmsOut" 
                                 channel="outbound"
                                 connection-factory="remoteConnectionFactory"
                                 destination="destinationqueue" />

   <!-- reading queue  -->
   <bean id="sourceQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg index="0">
            <value>OutputQueue_7</value>
        </constructor-arg> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageListenerContainer"   
class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="remoteConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="sourceQueue"/>
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="10"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1"/>
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true"/>         
</bean>

<int:channel id="inbound"/>

<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn" 
                                        channel="inbound"
                                        extract-payload="false" 
                                        container="messageListenerContainer" />


    <int:service-activator input-channel="inbound"
                        output-channel="outbound"
                        ref="messageReader"
                        method="onMessage" />

</beans>


-- Message Reader Class

import javax.jms.JMSException;

import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("messageReader")
public class MessageReader
{

@ServiceActivator
public void onMessage(Message inboundMessage) {

    System.out.println(" -------Message Read Start--------");

    System.out.println(inboundMessage.getHeaders());

    System.out.println(" -------Message Headers Reading completed--------");

    System.out.println("payload-->" + inboundMessage.getPayload().getClass());
    String payload = inboundMessage.getPayload().toString();
    System.out.println("payload value-->" + payload);


    org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTextMessage obj = (org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTextMessage)inboundMessage.getPayload();
    System.out.println("Object-->" + obj);

    String var = null;
    try {
        var = obj.getText();
        System.out.println("Datastructure-->" + obj.getText());
    } catch (JMSException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}


---- Message Writer Class

@Component("sendMessage")
public class SendMessage {

@Autowired
private MessageChannel outbound;


public void send(String name)
{
    Entity entity = new Entity(1,"anuj");

    Message<Entity> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(entity)
                                .setHeader("Message_Header1", "Message_Header1_Value")
                                .setHeader("Message_Header2", "Message_Header2_Value")
                                .build();

    outbound.send(message);
}

}


-- Application main class
public class App {

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:7_applicationContext.xml" );

    SendMessage sendMessage = (SendMessage)applicationContext.getBean( "sendMessage", SendMessage.class);

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        sendMessage.send("This is Message Content");
    }

    applicationContext.registerShutdownHook();
}

}
```

Comment: Don't you just want to use topics, instead of queues then?

Comment: I have use case of point-point communication. No pub-sub.

Comment: Can't we have messages stay in queue, till some other application actually removes the messages?

Comment: That's not point-to-point now, right? In point-to-point MQ communication:
Messages are put on the queue, read from the queue, marked as being processed, and, after successfully processed, are acknowledged as being properly accepted, and then, removed from the queue. 
A message cannot be processed and left on the queue... unless the processing fails. If the processing fails, the message will be returned to the queue... which will deliver it to a client... quite possibly the same.

Comment: We want to keep it P2P as we want only one consumer to process the message.
Also, we want to persist the message because the Producer wants to keep the control of removing the message.

Comment: But what would the Consumer do after it has processed the message? It is consumed, after all. And what would happen in your setup when the producer then decides to remove the message (say, an hour later). 
Why would the producer need to keep control? 
It almost sounds like you're trying to create a manual two-phase-commit, instead of having a transaction exist between the producer and the consumer's messagehandler

Comment: Looks like that isn't a task for JMS. Consider to use DataBase for such a purpose. In Messaging terms producer doesn't care about message consumption. Its task just to be sure that message is places into the queue correctly. That's all.

Comment: Kool. It helped a lot. Thanks Koos. Thanks Artem.